# Laravel update function doesn't work and no error shown

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to update my database record with simple query in laravel controller.

This is my code,

```
DB::table('calender_events')->where('id', '=', '1')->update(
    array(
        'title' => $request->title,

    )
);
```

form

```
<form id="addEventForm" method="post" action="{{ route('editEvent.store') }}" autocomplete="off">
        @csrf
        <div class="pl-lg-4">
            <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('title') ? ' has-danger' : '' }}">
                <label class="form-control-label" for="input-title">{{ __('Title') }}</label>
                <div class="row">
                <div class="col">
                <input type="text" name="title" id="input-title" class="form-control form-control-alternative{{ $errors->has('title') ? ' is-invalid' : '' }}" placeholder="{{ __('Title') }}" value="{{ $old_event['title'] }}" required autofocus>
                </div>
                <div class="col">
                <p style="font-size:14px;padding: 10px;">Current Title: {{ $old_event['title'] }}</p>
                </div>
                </div>

                @if ($errors->has('title'))
                    <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                        <strong>{{ $errors->first('title') }}</strong>
                    </span>
                @endif
            </div>




             <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary mt-4">{{ __('Save') }}</button>

            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
```

when I click save button it redirect to home page as expected , but db doesn't get updated.
also I used insert and select queries without any error.
and yes,there is a record in database with id=1.
please help!

Comment: How about where('id',  1)?

Comment: I don't see an issue in the code, share the controller's update method with me if you can.

Comment: Instead of using DB facade, try `Event::find(1)->update(["title"=>$request->title]);`. But either should be working, given the code you've provided. Does the route "editEvent.store" exist?

Comment: it was Dashboard template I use some functions defined by it,but they blocks them for free version

Answer (score 1):

You should have to write the code like this

```
DB::table('calender_events')->where('id',1)->update(
   array(
      'title' => $request->title,

   )
);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the working code I finally come up with,

```js
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\User;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;
use Illuminate\Support\Str;
use Illuminate\Http\UploadedFile;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;

class EditUserController extends Controller
{
     /**
     * Update the specified user in storage
     *
     * @param  \App\Http\Request   $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse
     */
    public function update(Request $request)
    {
         $image = $request->file('avatar');
    if($image!=null){
        $avatar_name = $request->get('NIC').'.'.$image->getClientOriginalExtension();
        $folder = '/uploads/avatars/';
       // $filePath = $folder . $avatar_name;
        $this->uploadOne($image, $folder, 'public', $avatar_name);
    }else{
        $avatar_name = null;  
    } 
    DB::table('users')->where('id', '=', $request->user_id_)->update(
        array(
            'avatar_id' => $avatar_name,
            'name'=>$request->name,
            'NIC'=>$request->NIC,
            'email'=>$request->email,
            'current_job_position'=>$request->current_job_position,
            'birthday'=>$request->birthday,
            'anniversary'=>$request->anniversary,
            'phone_home'=>$request->phone_home,
            'phone_mobile'=>$request->phone_mobile,
            'address_permanent'=>$request->address_permanent,
            'address_temporary'=>$request->address_temporary,
            'branch'=>$request->branch,
            'bank'=>$request->bank,
            'bank_number'=>$request->bank_number,
            'user_role'=>$request->user_role,
            'supervisor_manager'=>$request->supervisor_manager,
            'next_kin_name'=>$request->next_kin_name,
            'next_kin_occupation'=>$request->next_kin_occupation,
            'next_kin_address'=>$request->next_kin_address,
            'next_kin_office_address'=>$request->next_kin_office_address,
            'next_kin_phone_mobile'=>$request->next_kin_phone_mobile,
            'next_kin_phone_home'=>$request->next_kin_phone_home,
            'updated_at'=>now()

        )
    );
        return redirect()->route('user.index')->withStatus(__('User successfully updated.'));
    }

     /**
     * Store a newly created user in storage
     *
     * @param  \App\Http\Request   $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse
     */
    public function store(Request $request)
    {

        
        $image = $request->file('avatar');
        $pass = Hash::make($request->password);
    if($image!=null){

        $avatar_name = $request->get('NIC').'.'.$image->getClientOriginalExtension();
        $folder = '/uploads/avatars/';
       // $filePath = $folder . $avatar_name;
        $this->uploadOne($image, $folder, 'public', $avatar_name);

        DB::table('users')->insert([
            [
            'avatar_id' => $avatar_name,   
            'name'=>$request->name,
            'NIC'=>$request->NIC,
            'email'=>$request->email,
            'password'=>$pass,
            'current_job_position'=>$request->current_job_position,
            'birthday'=>$request->birthday,
            'anniversary'=>$request->anniversary,
            'phone_home'=>$request->phone_home,
            'phone_mobile'=>$request->phone_mobile,
            'address_permanent'=>$request->address_permanent,
            'address_temporary'=>$request->address_temporary,
            'branch'=>$request->branch,
            'bank'=>$request->bank,
            'bank_number'=>$request->bank_number,
            'user_role'=>$request->user_role,
            'supervisor_manager'=>$request->supervisor_manager,
            'next_kin_name'=>$request->next_kin_name,
            'next_kin_occupation'=>$request->next_kin_occupation,
            'next_kin_address'=>$request->next_kin_address,
            'next_kin_office_address'=>$request->next_kin_office_address,
            'next_kin_phone_mobile'=>$request->next_kin_phone_mobile,
            'next_kin_phone_home'=>$request->next_kin_phone_home,
            'created_at'=>now(),
            ],
        ]);  
    }else{
        DB::table('users')->insert([
            [
            'name'=>$request->name,
            'NIC'=>$request->NIC,
            'email'=>$request->email,
            'password'=>$pass,
            'current_job_position'=>$request->current_job_position,
            'birthday'=>$request->birthday,
            'anniversary'=>$request->anniversary,
            'phone_home'=>$request->phone_home,
            'phone_mobile'=>$request->phone_mobile,
            'address_permanent'=>$request->address_permanent,
            'address_temporary'=>$request->address_temporary,
            'branch'=>$request->branch,
            'bank'=>$request->bank,
            'bank_number'=>$request->bank_number,
            'user_role'=>$request->user_role,
            'supervisor_manager'=>$request->supervisor_manager,
            'next_kin_name'=>$request->next_kin_name,
            'next_kin_occupation'=>$request->next_kin_occupation,
            'next_kin_address'=>$request->next_kin_address,
            'next_kin_office_address'=>$request->next_kin_office_address,
            'next_kin_phone_mobile'=>$request->next_kin_phone_mobile,
            'next_kin_phone_home'=>$request->next_kin_phone_home,
            'created_at'=>now(),
            ],
        ]);  
        }
    return redirect()->route('user.index')->withStatus(__('User successfully created.'));
    }

    public function uploadOne(UploadedFile $uploadedFile, $folder = null, $disk = 'public', $filename = null)
    {
        $name = !is_null($filename) ? $filename : Str::random(25);

        $path =storage_path('uploads/avatars/'.$filename.'');

        if( Storage::exists($path)){
          
         Storage::disk('public')->delete('uploads/avatars/'.$filename.'');  
        }
        $file = $uploadedFile->storeAs($folder, $name, $disk);
        return $file;
    }

}
```

```html
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
    @include('layouts.headers.cards')
    
    <div class="container-fluid mt--7">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xl-12 mb-5 mb-xl-0">
                <div class="card bg-white shadow">
                    <div class="card-body">
                    <form id="addEventForm" method="post" action="{{ route('editEvent.store') }}" autocomplete="off">
                            @csrf
                            <div class="pl-lg-4">
                            <input type="number" name="eventId" id="input-eventId" value="{{ $old_event['id'] }}" style="visibility:hidden;">
                                <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('title') ? ' has-danger' : '' }}">
                                    <label class="form-control-label" for="input-title">{{ __('Title') }}</label>
                                    <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col">
                                    <input type="text" name="title" id="input-title" class="form-control form-control-alternative{{ $errors->has('title') ? ' is-invalid' : '' }}" placeholder="{{ __('Title') }}" value="{{ $old_event['title'] }}" required autofocus>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col">
                                    <p style="font-size:14px;padding: 10px;">Current Title: {{ $old_event['title'] }}</p>
                                    </div>
                                    </div>

                                    @if ($errors->has('title'))
                                        <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                            <strong>{{ $errors->first('title') }}</strong>
                                        </span>
                                    @endif
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('description') ? ' has-danger' : '' }}">
                                    <label class="form-control-label" for="input-description">{{ __('Description') }}</label>
                                    <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col">
                                    <input type="text" name="description" id="input-description" class="form-control form-control-alternative{{ $errors->has('description') ? ' is-invalid' : '' }}" placeholder="{{ __('Description') }}" value="{{ $old_event['description'] }}" required autofocus>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col">
                                    <p style="font-size:14px;padding: 10px;">Current Description: {{ $old_event['description'] }}</p>
                                    </div>
                                    </div>
                                    @if ($errors->has('description'))
                                        <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                            <strong>{{ $errors->first('description') }}</strong>
                                        </span>
                                    @endif
                                </div>
                                
                                <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('startTime') ? ' has-danger' : '' }}">
                                    <label class="form-control-label" for="input-startTime">{{ __('Start Time') }}</label>
                                    <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col">
                                    <input type="time" name="startTime" id="input-startTime" class="form-control form-control-alternative{{ $errors->has('startTime') ? ' is-invalid' : '' }}" placeholder="{{ __('Start Time') }}" value="{{ old('startTime') }}" autofocus>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col">
                                    <p style="font-size:14px;padding: 10px;">Current Start time: {{ $old_event['startTime'] }}</p>
                                    </div>
                                    </div>
                                    @if ($errors->has('startTime'))
                                        <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                            <strong>{{ $errors->first('startTime') }}</strong>
                                        </span>
                                    @endif
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('endTime') ? ' has-danger' : '' }}">
                                    <label class="form-control-label" for="input-endTime">{{ __('End Time') }}</label>
                                    <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col">
                                    <input type="time" name="endTime" id="input-endTime" class="form-control form-control-alternative{{ $errors->has('endTime') ? ' is-invalid' : '' }}" placeholder="{{ __('End Time') }}" value="{{ old('endTime') }}" autofocus>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col">
                                    <p style="font-size:14px;padding: 10px;">Current End time: {{ $old_event['endTime'] }}</p>
                                    </div>
                                    </div>
                                    @if ($errors->has('endTime'))
                                        <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                            <strong>{{ $errors->first('endTime') }}</strong>
                                        </span>
                                    @endif
                                </div>
                                <fieldset style="border:groove;padding:5px;">
                                <legend style="font-size:12px;">  &nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp One day event (set this values only for one day event)</legend>
                                
                                <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('start') ? ' has-danger' : '' }}">
                                    <label class="form-control-label" for="input-start">{{ __('Start') }}</label>
                                    <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col">
                                    <input type="date" name="start" id="input-start" class="form-control form-control-alternative{{ $errors->has('start') ? ' is-invalid' : '' }}" placeholder="{{ __('Start') }}"  autofocus>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col">
                                    <p style="font-size:14px;padding: 10px;">Current Start date: {{ $old_event['start'] }}</p>
                                    </div>
                                    </div>
                                    @if ($errors->has('start'))
                                        <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                            <strong>{{ $errors->first('start') }}</strong>
                                        </span>
                                    @endif
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('end') ? ' has-danger' : '' }}">
                                    <label class="form-control-label" for="input-end">{{ __('End') }}</label>
                                    <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col">
                                    <input type="date" name="end" id="input-end" class="form-control form-control-alternative{{ $errors->has('end') ? ' is-invalid' : '' }}" placeholder="{{ __('End') }}"  autofocus>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col">
                                    <p style="font-size:14px;padding: 10px;">Current End date: {{ $old_event['end'] }}</p>
                                    </div>
                                    </div>
                                    @if ($errors->has('end'))
                                        <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                            <strong>{{ $errors->first('end') }}</strong>
                                        </span>
                                    @endif
                                </div>
                                </fieldset>
                                <fieldset style="border:groove;padding:5px;">
                                <legend style="font-size:12px;">  &nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp Recurring event (set this values if event is recurring)</legend>
                                
                                <div  class="form-group{{ $errors->has('startRecur') ? ' has-danger' : '' }}">
                                    <label class="form-control-label" for="input-startRecur">{{ __('Start Recurring') }}</label>
                                    <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col">
                                    <input type="date"  name="startRecur" id="input-startRecur" class="form-control form-control-alternative{{ $errors->has('startRecur') ? ' is-invalid' : '' }}" placeholder="{{ __('Start Recurring') }}" value="{{ old('startRecur') }}" autofocus>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col">
                                    <p style="font-size:14px;padding: 10px;">Current Start date: {{ $old_event['startRecur'] }}</p>
                                    </div>
                                    </div>
                                    @if ($errors->has('startRecur'))
                                        <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                            <strong>{{ $errors->first('startRecur') }}</strong>
                                        </span>
                                    @endif
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('endRecur') ? ' has-danger' : '' }}">
                                    <label class="form-control-label" for="input-endRecur">{{ __('End Recurring') }}</label>
                                    <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col">
                                    <input type="date" name="endRecur" id="input-endRecur" class="form-control form-control-alternative{{ $errors->has('endRecur') ? ' is-invalid' : '' }}" placeholder="{{ __('End Recurring') }}" value="{{ old('endRecur') }}" autofocus>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col">
                                    <p style="font-size:14px;padding: 10px;">Current End date: {{ $old_event['endRecur'] }}</p>
                                    </div>
                                    </div>
                                    @if ($errors->has('endRecur'))
                                        <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                            <strong>{{ $errors->first('endRecur') }}</strong>
                                        </span>
                                    @endif
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('daysOfWeek') ? ' has-danger' : '' }}">
                                    <label class="form-control-label" for="input-daysOfWeek">{{ __('Days of week') }}</label>
                                    <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col">
                                    <select multiple size="7" name="daysOfWeek[]" id="input-daysOfWeek" class="form-control form-control-alternative{{ $errors->has('daysOfWeek') ? ' is-invalid' : '' }}" placeholder="{{ __('days Of Week') }}"   autofocus>
  
                                    <option value="0">Sunday</option>
                                    <option value="1">Monday</option>
                                    <option value="2">Tuesday</option>
                                    <option value="3">Wednesday</option>
                                    <option value="4">Thursday</option>
                                    <option value="5">Friday</option>
                                    <option value="6">Saturday</option>

                                    
                                    </select>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col">
                                    <p style="font-size:14px;padding: 10px;">Current selected days: {{ $old_event['daysOfWeek'] }}</p>
                                    </div>
                                    </div>
                                    @if ($errors->has('daysOfWeek'))
                                        <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                            <strong>{{ $errors->first('daysOfWeek') }}</strong>
                                        </span>
                                    @endif
                                </div>
                                </fieldset>
                                <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('assignesto') ? ' has-danger' : '' }}">
                                    <label class="form-control-label" for="input-assignesto">{{ __('assignes to') }}</label>
                                    <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col">
                                    <select multiple size="3" name="assignesto[]" id="input-assignesto" class="form-control form-control-alternative{{ $errors->has('assignesto') ? ' is-invalid' : '' }}" placeholder="{{ __('assignesto') }}"  required autofocus>

                                    @foreach($assignees_array as $key)
                                     
                                    <option value="{{ $key->id }}">{{ $key->name }}</option>

                                    @endforeach
                                    </select>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col">
                                    <p style="font-size:14px;padding: 10px;">Current assignees: {{ $old_event['assigned_to_string'] }}</p>
                                    </div>
                                    </div>
                                    @if ($errors->has('assignesto'))
                                        <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                            <strong>{{ $errors->first('assignesto') }}</strong>
                                        </span>
                                    @endif
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('location') ? ' has-danger' : '' }}">
                                    <label class="form-control-label" for="input-location">{{ __('location') }}</label>
                                    <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col">
                                    <input type="text" name="location" id="input-location" class="form-control form-control-alternative{{ $errors->has('location') ? ' is-invalid' : '' }}" placeholder="{{ __('location') }}" value="{{ $old_event['location'] }}" required autofocus>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col">
                                    <p style="font-size:14px;padding: 10px;">Current Location: {{ $old_event['location'] }}</p>
                                    </div>
                                    </div>
                                    @if ($errors->has('location'))
                                        <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                            <strong>{{ $errors->first('location') }}</strong>
                                        </span>
                                    @endif
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('notes') ? ' has-danger' : '' }}">
                                    <label class="form-control-label" for="input-notes">{{ __('notes') }}</label>
                                    <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col">
                                    <input type="text" name="notes" id="input-notes" class="form-control form-control-alternative{{ $errors->has('notes') ? ' is-invalid' : '' }}" placeholder="{{ __('notes') }}" value="{{ $old_event['notes'] }}" required autofocus>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col">
                                    <p style="font-size:14px;padding: 10px;">Current Notes: {{ $old_event['notes'] }}</p>
                                    </div>
                                    </div>
                                    @if ($errors->has('notes'))
                                        <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                            <strong>{{ $errors->first('notes') }}</strong>
                                        </span>
                                    @endif
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('notes') ? ' has-danger' : '' }}">
                                    
                                    <p style="font-size:14px;padding: 10px;">Event created by: {{ $old_event['assigned_by_detail'] }}</p>
                                    
                                </div>
                                <div class="modal-footer">
                                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary mt-4">{{ __('Save') }}</button>
                                    
                                </div>
                            </div>
      </form>
  
                    </div> 
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <script>

</script>
        @include('layouts.footers.auth')
    </div>
@endsection

@push('js')

    <script src="{{ asset('argon') }}/vendor/chart.js/dist/Chart.min.js"></script>
    <script src="{{ asset('argon') }}/vendor/chart.js/dist/Chart.extension.js"></script>

@endpush
```

I had to make another blade and move edit functions to another controller.And this was because of free dashboard template I'm using.It has built in authentication functions but  blocks some parts for free users.Anyway thanks for your help.